# Is it possible to create a JAR with an aspect that is automatically applied to classes in client project?

Tags: java, servlets, aspectj, spring-aop, aspect

I want to have a JAR with an aspect that intercepts all method calls, e.g.

```
@Aspect
public class CoolAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod() { }

    @Before("anyPublicMethod()")
    public void advice(JoinPoint point) {
       System.out.println("sign:\t" + point.getSignature());
    }
}
```

Suppose the above is the aspect I have and want clients to use. I compile it to a JAR and make available to Maven.

Now the clients would use this jar as a dependency, e.g.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cool-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>cool-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This artifact (JAR) has the mentioned aspect.

Now is it possible for the aspect work **by just declaring a Maven dependency**?

Few things that might be important:

1. I plan to use AspectJ (perhaps Spring AOP, if necessary),
2. The clients will probably be web applications with normal `web.xml` etc.
3. Clients are built with Maven
4. I want the Clients to be as easy to configure as possible - in my original idea a Maven dependency would be enough.
5. The "Annotation JAR" will contain a web-fragment, so it's possible to declare some custom `ServletContextListener` there..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Find a simple solustion for this question if you are using spring-boot:

In the jar, you can define your aspect as a component:

```
package com.xxx.yy.zz.aspect;
@Aspect
@Component
public class CoolAspect {
   // code like the question
}
```

And the, you need create a file `spring.factories` in `/resources/META-INF/`.
Spring will scan this file when start.

And the file `spring.factories`

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.xxx.yy.zz.aspect.CoolAspect
```

After that, just package them as a jar.

This will work **by just declaring a Maven dependency**

Comment: This helped me a lot, I created a library with some aspects and other utilities, and it didn't work until I applied this.

Comment: You saved me! I did just that and it worked! very good

Answer (score 2):

**No, this is impossible**, because AspectJ must be started prior to any client classes. All client classes should be loaded through a special enhanced class loader, which will process annotations.

**The other thing is Spring's AOP**. it weaves beans during application context start up and does not require special class loader. That would be the easiest way for client if he uses spring. Add maven dependency and then configure AOP in the application context.

[There are four types of weaving:](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html)

- Compile-time weaving is the simplest approach. When you have the
  source code for an application, ajc will compile from source and
  produce woven class files as output. The invocation of the weaver is
  integral to the ajc compilation process. The aspects themselves may
  be in source or binary form. If the aspects are required for the
  affected classes to compile, then you must weave at compile-time.
  Aspects are required, e.g., when they add members to a class and
  other classes being compiled reference the added members.
- Post-compile weaving (also sometimes called binary weaving) is used
  to weave existing class files and JAR files. As with compile-time
  weaving, the aspects used for weaving may be in source or binary
  form, and may themselves be woven by aspects.
- Load-time weaving (LTW) is simply binary weaving defered until the
  point that a class loader loads a class file and defines the class to
  the JVM. To support this, one or more "weaving class loaders", either
  provided explicitly by the run-time environment or enabled through a
  "weaving agent" are required.
- Run-time weaving, this is what actually Spring is doing. We
  define this as the weaving of classes that have already been defined.
  to the JVM

Comment: OK, thanks. Good to know that at least Spring gives an opportunity for this to work. But do you have an idea/snippet of how to configure spring in "aspect jar"?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/aop.html - here is a documentation. You pack aspects in a jar, client then adds maven dependency and inserts them into application context.

Comment: See that's the thing. I don't want the client to insert them into application context. It's trivial then. The clients might as well have no application context because they don't use spring. This aspect should work for normal classes e.g. servlets registered in client's  `web.xml`

Comment: Iam afraid just by adding maven dependency this is impossible to accomplish. You should chose the least evil. ;)